# legitimate use of GC.Collect?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Consider this code which uses the System.Threading.Timer class.

```
mTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(someTimer, null, dueTime.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Now I have a list with times  every day the timer function must execute and then it resets the timer to the next time it should execute.

```
private static void someTimer(object state)
{
  TimeSpan dueTime = GetDueTime();
  mTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(someTimer, null,      (int)dueTime.TotalMilliseconds, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

but I noticed that the timer function executes multiple times after a while and it seems to have to do with the garbage collector. The old object will still be firing events **until** it is garbage collected.

So a simple GC.Collect(0) fixed it, timer function executes only once.
I know the common opinion is that one should never have to use manually call the garbage collector, so my question is if this is a legitimate use of GC.Collect?
How else should one fix this?

Comment: Why are you re-assigning the timer instead of just changing it?

Comment: weow. because I didnt know about the Change function...al right, no good use of GC.Collect here either

Comment: @RonBeyer You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The System.Threading.Timer has a [Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.change(v=vs.110).aspx) method that allows you to modify the timer instead of recreating a new one.

The problem, as you've discovered in a round-about way, is that just because you re-assign the object doesn't mean that the "old" one doesn't keep firing. This has to do with attached event handlers to an object (that can keep zombie objects alive) or queued thread pool callbacks in this case. `Dispose` won't guarantee that you won't get another callback because the callbacks are queued by the Thread Pool and won't clear until the callback is called the next time.

The recommended way is to use the Change function.

Comment: How is possible, that `Timer` is firing event multiple times, if period is set to infinite?

Comment: It shouldn't be, its separate instances of it doing it, I'm not sure about the rest of the code, multiple places may call this function or "reset" the timer.

Comment: If you need some sophisticated scheduling, maybe try Quartz.net?

Answer (score 0):

You should `Dispose()` the timer when you no longer want it to fire events.

Comment: Actually the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0225y6(v=vs.110).aspx) say _Callbacks can occur after the Dispose() method overload has been called._

Comment: @juharr Yes, but that's not the issue here. The note in the docs is concerned with the usual thread-safety issues - `Dispose` *will* prevent any postings in the future. It just cannot do anything about the callbacks already scheduled (obviously).